# Error when trying to insert the data from the cart to the new tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$x = $i + 1;
        $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="' . $product_name . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="' . $price . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
```

versus

```
// Dynamic Checkout Btn Assembly
    $x = $i + 1;
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_' . $x . '" value="' . $product_name . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_' . $x . '" value="' . $price . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity_' . $x . '" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
```

with the above input data where i set up another page to retrieve the data

```
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['cartOutput'])) { 

$sql= 'INSERT INTO orders (product_name, price, quantity, date_added) VALUES(?,?,?, NOW())';      

$stmt = $myConnection->prepare($sql); 
$countArray = count($_POST["item_name"]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $countArray; $i++) {
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['item_name'][$i], $_POST['amount'][$i], $_POST['quantity'][$i]);
$stmt->execute();
}

echo $sql   ; 

exit();
}
?>
```

this retrieve with the 1st one above but it skipped the first item_name[] in the cart where as the second one above failed to retrieve data using $_POST["item_name"] any other words I can use in order to retrieve data from the second one?

```
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 4 (if user wants to remove an item from cart)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] != "") {
    // Access the array and run code to remove that array index
    $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];
    if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]);
        sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
}
?>
```

it actually affected my indexes..where after the implement of item_name[] or item_name[ ' . $x . ] ..it remove the line one down..eg first line click remove, it remove the second line, if click second line, it remove the third line, if nothing in third line, it show no response

```
Array ( [cartOutput] =>   Array ( [ 1 ] => 123 ) [quantity] => Array ( [ 1 ] => 1 ) [custom] => 19-1, ) array(4) { ["cartOutput"]=> string(44) "   array(1) { [" 1 "]=> string(3) "123" } ["quantity"]=> array(1) { [" 1 "]=> string(1) "1" } ["custom"]=> string(5) "19-1," } 
Notice: Undefined index: item_name in /home/u382560552/public_html/order_list.php on line 23
INSERT INTO orders (product_name, price, quantity, date_added) VALUES(?,?,?, NOW())
```

the above is printr(POST) and vardump(POST) for item_name[ ' . x . ' ]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Your Cart</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
  <div id="pageHeader"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="12">
  <tr>
    <td width="32%"><a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/index.php"><img src="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/style/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" width="252" height="36" border="0" /></a></td>
    <td width="68%" align="left">Your Cart</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/index.php">Home</a> &nbsp; &middot; &nbsp; <a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/product_list.php">Products</a> &nbsp; &middot; &nbsp; <a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/help.php">Help</a> &nbsp; &middot; &nbsp; <a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/contact.php">Contact</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>  <div id="pageContent">
    <div style="margin:24px; text-align:left;">

    <br />
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
      <tr>
        <td width="18%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Product</strong></td>
        <td width="45%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Product Description</strong></td>
        <td width="10%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Unit Price</strong></td>
        <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
        <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Total</strong></td>
        <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Remove</strong></td>
      </tr>
     <tr><td><a href="product.php?id=13">BiO-LiFE BIO-VIZION 100 + 30 CAPS</a><br /><img src="inventory_images/13.jpg" alt="BiO-LiFE BIO-VIZION 100 + 30 CAPS" width="40" height="52" border="1" /></td><td>Provides the natural carotenoids lutein & zeaxanthin, plus The A.C.E. & Zinc antioxidants. Lutein and zeaxanthin are naturally present in the macula of the human retina. BiO-LiFE Bio-Vizion is a unique formula that provides a source of lutein and zeaxanthin preserved in their natural form from marigold flowers. It is also formulated with other anti free-radical nutrients such as Vitamin A,C,E plus the mineral zinc and selenium.

Features:

Dosage: Adult - One capsule daily with food or as recommended by your pharmacist.
Dosage: Children (6-12 yrs): One capsule every other day with food or as recommended by your pharmacist.
100 tablets per bottle or box</td><td>$140.00</td><td><form action="cart.php" method="post">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="1" size="1" maxlength="2" />
        <input name="adjustBtn13" type="submit" value="change" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="13" />
        </form></td><td>   $140.00</td><td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn13" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="0" /></form></td></tr>     <!-- <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr> -->
    </table>
    <div style='font-size:18px; margin-top:12px;' align='right'>Cart Total :    $140.00 USD</div>    <br />
<br />
<form action="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/order_list.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cartOutput" id="cartOutput" value = "<?php echo $cartOutput; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name[1]" value="BiO-LiFE BIO-VIZION 100 + 30 CAPS">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount[1]" value="140.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity[1]" value="1">  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="13-1,">

    <input type="submit" id="cartOutput" value="Submit">
    </form>    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="cart.php?cmd=emptycart">Click Here to Empty Your Shopping Cart</a>
    </div>
   <br />
  </div>
  <div id="pageFooter">Copyright | <a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/storeadmin/">Admin</a></div></div>
</body>
</html><script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-5263515-4']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.3eeweb.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

the above is html view source

```
<?php 
// This file is www.developphp.com curriculum material
// Written by Adam Khoury January 01, 2011
// http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=442E340A42191003
session_start(); // Start session first thing in script
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php"; 
?>
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 1 (if user attempts to add something to the cart from the product page)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $wasFound = false;
    $i = 0;
    // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
        // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
        $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
    } else {
        // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                      $wasFound = true;
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
           } // close foreach loop
           if ($wasFound == false) {
               array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
           }
    }
    header("location: cart.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 2 (if user chooses to empty their shopping cart)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] == "emptycart") {
    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
}
?>
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 3 (if user chooses to adjust item quantity)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
    // execute some code
    $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but numbers
    if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }
    if ($quantity < 1) { $quantity = 1; }
    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
    } // close foreach loop
}
?>
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 4 (if user wants to remove an item from cart)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] != "") {
    // Access the array and run code to remove that array index
    $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];
    if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]);
        sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
}
?>
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 5  (render the cart for the user to view on the page)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$cartOutput = "";
$cartTotal = "";
$pp_checkout_btn = '';
$product_id_array = '';
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
} else {
        // Start PayPal Checkout Button
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<form action="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/order_list.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cartOutput" id="cartOutput" value = "<?php echo $cartOutput; ?>
    ';
    // Start the For Each loop
    $i = 0; 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
                $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1";
        $sql = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $details = $row["details"];
        }
        $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
        $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_US");
        $pricetotal = money_format("%10.2n", $pricetotal);
// Dynamic Checkout Btn Assembly
    $x = $i + 1;
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name[' . $x . ']" value="' . $product_name . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount[' . $x . ']" value="' . $price . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity[' . $x . ']" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
        // Create the product array variable
        $product_id_array .= "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].","; 
        // Dynamic table row assembly
        $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
        $cartOutput .= '<td><a href="product.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br /><img src="inventory_images/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name. '" width="40" height="52" border="1" /></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $details . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>$' . $price . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        </form></td>';
        //$cartOutput .= '<td>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $pricetotal . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
        $i++; 
    } 
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_US");
    $cartTotal = money_format("%10.2n", $cartTotal);
    $cartTotal = "<div style='font-size:18px; margin-top:12px;' align='right'>Cart Total : ".$cartTotal." USD</div>";
    // Finish the Paypal Checkout Btn
    $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $product_id_array . '">

    <input type="submit" id="cartOutput" value="Submit">
    </form>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Your Cart</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
  <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
  <div id="pageContent">
    <div style="margin:24px; text-align:left;">

    <br />
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
      <tr>
        <td width="18%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Product</strong></td>
        <td width="45%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Product Description</strong></td>
        <td width="10%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Unit Price</strong></td>
        <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
        <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Total</strong></td>
        <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Remove</strong></td>
      </tr>
     <?php echo $cartOutput; ?>
     <!-- <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr> -->
    </table>
    <?php echo $cartTotal; ?>
    <br />
<br />
<?php echo $pp_checkout_btn; ?>
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="cart.php?cmd=emptycart">Click Here to Empty Your Shopping Cart</a>
    </div>
   <br />
  </div>
  <?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

actual form as requested

Comment: Show `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: What does the HTML of the form look like when you `View Source`?

Comment: edited and posted html view source from google chrome

Comment: Where is `item_name[1]` coming from? Your PHP code writes `item_name[]`.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up inline PHP with echoed strings, so `<?php echo $cartOutput; ?>` ended up in your HTML output. But I don't see anything like that in the PHP code at the top. I think you've changed your PHP from what you originally posted. Could you update the question to show the actual code that's writing the form?

Comment: added actual form..appreciate that someone trying to help me outthere =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
$pp_checkout_btn .= '<form action="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/order_list.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cartOutput" id="cartOutput" value = "<?php echo $cartOutput; ?>
';
```

You don't use `<?php` when interpolating in a string. It should be:

```
$pp_checkout_btn .= '<form action="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/order_list.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cartOutput" id="cartOutput" value = "$cartOutput">';
```

And change this:

```
$x = $i + 1;
$pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name[' . $x . ']" value="' . $product_name . '">
<input type="hidden" name="amount[' . $x . ']" value="' . $price . '">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity[' . $x . ']" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
```

to:

```
$pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="' . $product_name . '">
<input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="' . $price . '">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
```

This will let PHP fill in the array indexes, starting from 0; you were starting from 1.

Finally, you have two elements with `id="cartOutput"`: the hidden input and the submit button. You need to rename one of them, because IDs must be unique. Or remove the IDs if they're not used for anything.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `name="item_name_' . $x . '"` to `name="item_name[' . $x . ']"`

Please note it is an array

That is how you are taking the values in your php code : `$_POST['item_name'][$i]`

Make this change for all the input fields.

Comment: it actually work but with the issue of `code` item_name[] as well that the first item_name not get picked up..

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST)` and see what is coming there

Comment: i am total noob..where should i put this print_r

Comment: Just above this : `if (isset($_POST['cartOutput'])) {` and submit your form.

Comment: weird i have changed to all of three to  name="item_name[ ' . $x . ' ]"  this format but now it show this error when posting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)  on line 16

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: item_name in /home/u382560552/public_html/order_list.php on line 21 when i used name="item_name[' . $x . ']

Comment: i put the print_r($_POST) above if (isset($_POST['cartOutput'])) but it show Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) on line 16

Comment: Array ( [cartOutput] =>   Array ( [ 1 ] => 123 ) [quantity] => Array ( [ 1 ] => 1 ) [custom] => 19-1, ) 
Notice: Undefined index: item_name in /home/u382560552/public_html/order_list.php on line 21
INSERT INTO orders (product_name, price, quantity, date_added) VALUES(?,?,?, NOW())

Comment: i forogot the ; after the print_r post..now it show the above code